# Calling saga from within

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to call a Saga from within (see example below) but when I send use put, this is not being taken. Example:

```
function * example () {
  while (true) {
    yield take('initialAction')
    const someAction = yield call(apiClient.someClientAction, parameter)
    yield put({ type: initialAction' })
  }
}
```

I wonder if this is the correct pattern or maybe am I missing something in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in a solution, see below:

```
function * example () {
  const chan = yield actionChannel('initialAction') 
  while (true) {
    yield take(chan)
    const someAction = yield call(apiClient.someClientAction, parameter)
    yield put({ type: initialAction' })
  }
}
```

For more information, [check the documentation](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html) 
and the [github answer](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/618)